# always show My Account & Wish List user logged in or not

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

Am new in magento 2 and also no experience in magento 1. I'm try to show My Account & Wish List links in top nav link in my custom theme (parent: Magento/luma ) like blank theme. I try with Magento/blank parent but still not show my account & wish list link. i try to add this script

> app/design/frontend/Package/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
           <referenceBlock name="register-link" />   
           <referenceBlock name="authorization-link"  />    
           <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link"  />       
           <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" />      
        </referenceBlock>
      </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy default.xml in your theme

**If you extend luma theme**

> app/design/frontend/Prince/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
               <!-- Add Your Link Here -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Contact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**If you extend blank theme**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
               <!-- Add your link here -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Contact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```